# Stop Preview from opening every file in its own page

Tags: preview

Every single time I open a picture to view in preview or preview itself it opens every document in a individual page. Which must be forced quit to close?

I have already tried going to System Preferences → General to make sure "Close windows when quitting an app" is unchecked. Using command-option-Q and command-option-w do not work either.

This happens with every single photo folder or individual picture I attempt to look at. For example, clicking on a photo in a folder opens opens 247 documents with 247 different pages?

How do I stop this? Can I remove Preview and use any other picture viewing option?

Comment: Do you have more then one login account on your Mac and if yes does this behavior exist under all accounts?  If you only have the one login account can to create a local test account (_not using a name@domain.com user name_) and see if the behavior exists there too?

Comment: checked but only one apple account on mac. only ever has been.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what version of OS X you're using and I don't know it Preview in different versions of OS X have different preferences however, in OS X 10.8 anyway, I went into Previews's Preferences (Preview > Preferences... > General) and changed what I assume is the default of **Open groups of files in the same window**, since I've never changed Previews's Preferences before now, to **Open all files in one window**, as shown in the image below.

With **Open groups of files in the same window** selected and when only opening one file at a time the default behavior is to open each file in its own window until it's changed to **Open all files in one window**.

[image]

Comment: am using mac os version 10.7.5

Comment: and this also does not work i have tried this also